# Migrating EPI5 from IIS6 to IIS7.5

Tags: iis, episerver

Trying to move an EPI5 site from a server with IIS6 to a server with IIS7.5.

Having problems because of the configuration being set up for IIS6. Ive tried to follow instructions
http://world.episerver.com/en/Documentation/Items/Tech-Notes/EPiServer-CMS-5/EPiServer-CMS-5-R2-SP1/Changes-Between-IIS6-and-IIS7/#Changes in web.config

Does anyone have experience of following this guide or reconfiguring from IIS6 to IIS7.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I've done in this situation (numerous times) is install a fresh (blank/demo) EPiServer 5 site on a server with IIS 7 and use those config files as a template when moving the real site from IIS 6 to IIS 7.

Comment: Interesting! So you install the EPI6 just to see a proper config and grab the parts that are different?

Comment: Basically - yes :-). You just have to be a bit careful when you merge the two configs so you don't accidentally use default settings from the fresh EPi6 config where you have site-specific settings from the old site.

Comment: I just realized I may have read something into your question that isn't there - you are moving an EPi 5 site between IIS versions, not upgrading to EPi 6? The same modus applies though, install a fresh EPi 5 site on an IIS7.5 and use that as your template. No need to involve EPi 6 if you're not upgrading. I changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: No Anders. You are correct. Im changing from
EPI5 IIS6
to
EPI6 IIS7.5

Answer (score 0):

EPiServer 4 on Windows 2008 with IIS7 is not officially supported. You can get it to work though - one key is to run the application pool in Classic mode.

EDIT: You also need to turn on the pool's "32-bit" setting.

Comment: Typo! Im starting with EPI 5, not 4.